# How can postMessage be used as an alternative to nextTick or setTimeout(__, 0)?

Tags: javascript

I've heard that postMessage is Google Chrome's implementation of nextTick. I'm a little confused by this statement since I thought that postMessage was used to communicate between web workers.

I've tried expressions like `postMessage(function() {return;});`, and that only errs instead of scheduling a function to be run when the event loop is idle. It seems that postMessage only takes a message as expected.

How can postMessage be used as means of scheduling function calls when the event loop is idle?

Comment: There is an old hack that produces a faster `setTimeout(fn, 0)` using `postMessage` by posting a message to yourself - it gets dispatched asynchronously but without the overhead of the timers queue. Note that it is no longer used and typically a `MutationObserver` hack is used instead.

Comment: Here - some reading material: http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Chrome actually runs on V8 which has a notion of a microtask queue. The `postMessage` part is part of the DOM API and it schedules a microtask - similarly to what `nextTick` does in node (although the chromium loop cycle is very different from Node's).

There is an old hack that uses postMessage to simulate a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` that looks something like this:

```
var queue = [];
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    if((e.source !== window) || (e.data === "flush")) return; // not the right message
    queue.forEach(function(fn){ fn(); }); // call all functions;
    queue = []; // clean the queue;
});

function nextTick(fn){
    queue.push(fn); // add the function
    window.postMessage(fn, "flush", "*");
}
```

There are clever tricks using `MessageChannel` instead of the window directly but it's all the same idea.

You can find old mentions of this technique [in this blog post](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts) it is rarely used anymore since there is a faster hack for a faster setTimeout using mutation observers.

Here is [a relatively modern source](https://github.com/kriskowal/asap/blob/master/browser-raw.js) on different techniques.

Comment: `window.postMessage(fn, "flush", "*");` is there a typo? Why pass `fn` to `possmessage`?

Comment: [postMessage](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#dom-window-postmessage) ain't the microtask this is a task that queued in the post message task queue